# Count number of arguments to Excel formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to use VBA to determine the number of arguments passed to an Excel formula. For instance, suppose a cell contains the formula =MyFunc($A$1, "xyz", SUM(1,2,COUNT(C1:C12)), IF(B1>2,1,0)). Then the counter function should return 4. Does VBA contain any built-in functions for this, or does someone have an example of a regular expression that could calculate this?

#### Update:

Thank you both user225626 and Charles. One problem I found was when there were quoted string arguments that contained commas; these commas were causing the argument count to increase. I've modified Charles' code to account for this.

```
Public Function CountFormulaArguments(sStr As String) As Integer
    Dim strChar As String
    Dim nArgs As Integer
    Dim n, nLParen, nCommas As Integer
    Dim blArray, bQuote As Boolean
    
    nLParen = 0
    nArgs = 0
    For n = 1 To Len(sStr)
        strChar = Mid(sStr, n, 1)
        If strChar = "(" Then
            nLParen = nLParen + 1
            If nLParen = 1 Then nArgs = nArgs + 1
        ElseIf strChar = ")" Then nLParen = nLParen - 1
        ElseIf nLParen = 1 And strChar = "{" Then blArray = True
        ElseIf blArray And strChar = "}" Then blArray = False
        ElseIf Not bQuote And strChar = """" Then bQuote = True
        ElseIf bQuote And strChar = """" Then bQuote = False
        ElseIf nLParen = 1 And Mid(sStr, n, 1) = "," And Not blArray And Not bQuote Then nCommas = nCommas + 1
        End If
    Next
    nArgs = nArgs + nCommas
    
    CountFormulaArguments = nArgs
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend `Test01` to allow for array constants and multiple function calls in one statement:

```
=SUM({1,2,3,4,5},{1,2})+SUM({1,2,3,4,5})<br/><br/>
```

Code:

```
Sub Test02()
    sStr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Formula

    For n = 1 To Len(sStr)
        strChar = Mid(sStr, n, 1)
        If strChar = "(" Then
            nLParen = nLParen + 1
            If nLParen = 1 Then nArgs = nArgs + 1
        End If
        If strChar = ")" Then nLParen = nLParen - 1

        If nLParen = 1 And strChar = "{" Then blArray = True
        If blArray And strChar = "}" Then blArray = False
        If nLParen = 1 And Mid(sStr, n, 1) = "," And Not blArray Then nCommas = nCommas + 1
    Next
    nArgs = nArgs + nCommas

    MsgBox nArgs
End Sub
```

Comment: Reached this post from [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30514386/vba-that-understands-excel-formula-contents) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test01()
 sStr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Formula

 For n = 1 To Len(sStr)
  If Mid(sStr, n, 1) = "(" Then nLParen = nLParen + 1
  If Mid(sStr, n, 1) = ")" Then nLParen = nLParen - 1

  If nLParen = 1 And Mid(sStr, n, 1) = "," Then nCommas = nCommas + 1
 Next
 nArgs = nCommas + 1

 MsgBox nArgs
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

UBOUND(array)

Why not just use the built-in UBOUND() function on the arguments in order to figure out how many have been fed to your user-defined function?

It is simple, but it will require you set at least one of your variables to have an unlimited count. Here is what I wrote for my purposes:

```
    Function My_Func(ParamArray others() as variable)

    n = UBound(others) + 1

    'insert code here

    howmanyargumentsinmyfunc = n

    End Function
```

Note:

- 'others' represents an unlimited number of arguments being fed into my function
- 'n' represents the total number of arguments (you have to add one because of how UBound deals with arrays)

UBound and ParamArray are the key built-in commands for figuring out how many variables get passed into the function. I suppose, if you needed to exclude certain values from being counted you could easily do so with some sort of countif.

I hope this helps somebody!